# MFC application DialogBased using propertyPage, DoModal() for a CDialog don't open any Dialog

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, mfc, dialog

In VS2013, i created an MFC Application Dialoged Based.
I modify the project in order to use PropertyPage and Propertysheet at the beginning of the application, so, instead of lauching a CDialog, it launch my propertypage.

After, I created a Dialog, and the class associates ( from::CdialogEx).
I would like to open this dialog behind a button click.

**Behind my button click, i do:**

```
CMyDialog myDialog;
myDialog.DoModal();
```

I don't have any error message, but, i don't show my Dialog at the screen.

Maybe it's because this dialog has no child no ?

Anyone could help me please ?

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Nixeus

EDIT :

**Here is my Entry point :**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "KenoApp.h"
#include "KenoDlg.h"

#include "GenerationDlg.h"
#include "KenoSheet.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CKenoApp

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CKenoApp, CWinApp)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, &CWinApp::OnHelp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// construction CKenoApp

CKenoApp::CKenoApp()
{

}


// Seul et unique objet CKenoApp

CKenoApp theApp;


// initialisation de CKenoApp

BOOL CKenoApp::InitInstance()
{
    AfxEnableControlContainer();

    // Standard initialization

#ifdef _AFXDLL
        // Call this when using MFC in a shared DLL
#else
    Enable3dControlsStatic();   // Call this when linking to MFC statically
#endif

    CKenoSheet KenoSheet;
    KenoSheet.SetTitle(L"Keno Helper v1.1");

    CGenerationDlg Generation;
    CKenoDlg KenoDlg;

    KenoSheet.AddPage(&KenoDlg);
    KenoSheet.AddPage(&Generation);

    //m_pMainWnd = &KenoSheet;

    int nResponse = KenoSheet.DoModal();

    // Since the dialog has been closed, return FALSE so that we exit the
    //  application, rather than start the application's message pump.
    return FALSE;
}
```

**And after, on my property page :**

```
CAboutDlg myDialog;
theApp.m_pMainWnd = &myDialog;
myDialog.DoModal();
```

My problem is now that, the DoModal() close my application.

Comment: Can you try displaying the Dialog as a modeless one?

Comment: No, how doing this ? I try to use the ShowWindow() method, bu i have an assert error !

Comment: Try the code at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yhth57kd.aspx

Comment: Trying, and error ( see at the top ) ;)

Comment: Have you looked to ensure that the code is finding the dialog resource?  Dialog creation typically fails when the resource cannot be found.

Comment: Hello, yes, my resource is ok ! After debug it appear that  CWnd::GetSafeHwnd() in AfxWin2.inl return false, but...why ?

Comment: Is there any rich edit or ActiveX on any of your property pages? Some controls need initialization.

Comment: Hello, no, and my property page, there is two buttons, four editbox, and a listbox ! That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix: In the `InitInstance()` of your application:

```
CMyPropSheet pps(_T("My Property Sheet"), NULL, 0);
//m_pMainWnd = &pps;        // *** remark away this line if you have it
int nResponse = pps.DoModal();
// do response ...

CTestDlg dlg;
m_pMainWnd = &dlg;          // this line is a must have
nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
// do response ...
```

The above code is assuming the PropertySheet and Dialog is to be launched  sequentially one after the other, inside the InitInstance() of the application. After more information from you, it seems that it is not the way you want it, so the above code is not applicable for your problem. Please revert your code back to the original before using my suggestion.

Comment: I tried your solution. Removed the line " m_pMainWnd = &pps " and add the line "theApp.m_pMainWnd = &myDialog" before the DoModal(), and my application close on the doModal() ! No error message, but close the application !

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni - What is the sequence of the Propertysheet and dialog launch, is it the same as in the code that I suggested, one after the other ? Or are you trying to start the dialog inside the Propertysheet ? The m_pMainWnd is supposed to be the one and only main window of the application. After it is set into the application class, the application will terminate itself once this m_pMainWnd handle become invalid/destroy.

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni - The above code is assuming the PropertySheet and Dialog is to be launched  sequentially one after the other, inside the InitInstance() of the application. After more information from you, it seems that it is not the way you want it, so the above code is not applicable for your problem. Please revert your code back to the original before using my suggestion.

Comment: @code123. My application directly launch a propertysheet instead of a dialog. My propertysheet is composed of two properypage. On the first propertypage, i have a button. I would like to launch my Dialog when the user click on the button. So, how doing this finnaly ?

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni - Thanks for the clarification, now I understand your UI implementation. In your case, the original code of `m_pMainWnd = &KenoSheet;` is correct and is needed. The `theApp.m_pMainWnd = &myDialog;` is not needed and should be removed, because the PropertySheet is valid througout the application execution so you only need to set it once and never change it again. Please ignore my answer and revert back the code.

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni - I actually tested out your code with my own dummy PropertySheet/Dialog class as the way that you implemented, and I encountered no problem at all activating the dialog within the PropertySheet button press. I think your dialog class may have some bugs that prevent it from being created. You should  test the dialog alone to isolate the problem and confirm that it can/cannot be created and the problem is/not cause by the PropertySheet. This can be done by replacing the PropertySheet with the dialog and run it under debug mode to figure out the problem.

Comment: Any important thing, i have solved it ! How ? I set the dialog style to DS_NOFAILCREATE. And it's ok ! But...why the create fail ? I have only one controle in my dialog, it's a button !

Comment: You only see the control which is OK, the button. You can't see the controls who failed to be created. What controls are in the rc file?

Comment: @manuell, Yes, Yes, and Yes :) You are right ! I checked with a texteditor the rc file and it appear it have a mistake due to a VS2013 bug in the resource editor !! I corrected my rc file and all is ok :) Probleme solved, thanks a lot for all the members who helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the result of `myDialog.DoModal();` call.

You can try the following piece of code:

Modeless:

```
CMyDialog myDialog = new CMyDialog();

if(myDialog != NULL)
{
    BOOL ret = myDialog->Create(10000, this);
    if(!ret)
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Error creating Dialog"));

    myDialog->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
else
{
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Error Creating Dialog Object"));
}
```

Comment: Hello, i tred, but, on the Creat(), i have an Assert Error.I attached the error message on the first initial thread.

Comment: Change `10000` in `Create(10000, this)` with the ID number of a dialog-box template resource.

Comment: Tell us the kind of ASSERT at this location.

Comment: Kind of assert at the WindowShow ?ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd) || (m_pCtrlSite != NULL));

Comment: It appear that the CWnd::GetSafeHwnd() in AfxWin2.inl return false.